# Computing SHA1 with ASP.NET Core

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, sha1, .net-core

I've got a ASP.NET 5 RC1 (soon to be ASP.NET Core) Web Application project.

It needs to compute SHA1 hashes.

Various `SHA1` subclasses are available and build under DNX 4.5.1, but there doesn't seem to be any available implementation under DNX Core 5.0.

Do I have to add a reference to bring that code in, or is it simply not available for .NET Core yet?

According to [this article](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/conceptual-overview/dotnetcore.html):

> .NET Core consists of a set of libraries, called “CoreFX”, and a small, optimized runtime, called “CoreCLR”.

Sure enough, in the CoreFX repo, there are no subclasses of `SHA1`:

https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/tree/master/src/System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms/src/System/Security/Cryptography

However in CoreCLR the subclasses are there as you'd expect, within mscorlib:

https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/tree/43b39a73cbf832ec13ec29ed356cb75834e7a8d7/src/mscorlib/src/System/Security/Cryptography

Why is there overlap between coreclr and corefx? Is this mscorlib code not available for .NET Core projects?

The description of the [`System.Security.Crytpography.Algorithms` package on NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms/4.0.0-beta-23516) says:

> Provides base types for cryptographic algorithms, including hashing, encryption, and signing operations.

Is there another package that includes actual algorithms and not just base classes? Is this something that simply hasn't been ported yet? Is there somewhere you can review the status of APIs and a roadmap, as Mono has?

Comment: CoreCLR is the Core runtime while CoreFX are the libraries. If SHA1 is part of the *runtime* itself, you should be able to use it. Have you tried creating implementations of the algorithm through the factory methods?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, hehe, completely missed the factory method (despite linking to it). With that, my code compiles. If you'd like to post that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Add the `System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms` nuget package.

Then

```
var sha1 = System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1.Create();

var hash = sha1.ComputeHash(myByteArray)
```

Comment: At the time of the comment, SHA1 is IDisposable and shoud be disposed with the using keyword:

"using var sha1 = System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1.Create();"

Answer (score 1):

string form of Sha1

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

public static string Sha1(string input)
{
    using var sha1 = SHA1.Create();
    var hash = sha1.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input));
    var sb = new StringBuilder(hash.Length * 2);

    foreach (byte b in hash)
    {
        sb.Append(b.ToString("x2"));
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```